# Editable Java Drawing2D Texts and Images

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

For a gym exercise machine, I need to modify continuously texts and images inside a JPanel.

`drawImage()` and `drawString()` worked fine, but they are 'dumb'. I have to repaint everything everytime.

The pseudo-code is the following:

```
public class CScreen extends JPanel {

    public CScreen()
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        BufferedImage img=...some image...;
        int ximg= ...variable location...;
        int yimg= ...variable location...;
        g.drawImage(img,ximg,yimg,...);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setFont(...);
        g2.setColor(...);

        String txt = ...some text...;
        int xtxt= ...variable location...;
        int ytxt= ...variable location...;
        g2.drawString(txt,xtxt,ytxt,...);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to deal with those text and images, as if they were objects, not pixels drawn?

Please, any help, will be really appreciated.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?  Swing provides `JLabel` for static text and multiple text components for editable text

Comment: I was unable to 'position' texts and images using Swing........ I am not doing anything 'out of the box'. Just changing text and reposition images for a 'look and feel' splash application for a gym exercise machine :)...

Comment: To me, that suggests you don't have an understanding of how layout managers work in Swing.  Trust me, you don't want to spend the time to invent the wheel that took hundreds if not thousands of people hours to create in the first place

Comment: I really appreciate this and i agree you, but well..... I really dont know how to relocate Swing object. Some people suggest me to go with the 'graphic' way. So i am lost. Most answers & suggestions so far ive reach always follow that way.

Comment: Please note, i am not developing a user window. This is for a look and feel   gym machine. I will update the answer with that information

Comment: Some idea of the layout your trying to achieve would also be useful

Comment: One of the nice things about dumb things is that they can be made smart. You can make a `Renderable` kind of interface you inherit from and start working with these things like objects, setting their properties and inserting to a canvas that iterates through them and automatically calls some abstract `render` method while you just focus on changing their properties. I usually want smart things to become dumber, ironically, as I often want them to be smart in a different way. Here you're lucky and can make the design the way you want it to be!

Comment: Wow, after so much time there is a kind of suggestion :).... I will give it a try and... well i will tell you.... :)